# Uniswap V2 swap tx - invalid codepoint at offset 22; missing continuation byte

Tags: rust, ethers.rs

So I have recently been using ethers-rs. I was forking mainnet using anvil, and I tried to front run an uniswap v2 swap. Every time I was trying to frontrun the transaction the frontrun swap was failing. But the exact same code was running smoothly when I wasn't trying to frontrun.

Here is the error I was seeing :

```json
 {
        "reason": "invalid codepoint at offset 22; missing continuation byte",
        "code": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "argument": "bytes",
        "value": {
                "0": 0,
                "1": 0,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 0,
                "4": 0,
                "5": 0,
                "6": 0,
                "7": 0,
                "8": 0,
                "9": 0,
                "10": 0,
                "11": 0,
                "12": 0,
                "13": 0,
                "14": 0,
                "15": 0,
                "16": 0,
                "17": 0,
                "18": 0,
                "19": 1,
                "20": 90,
                "21": 241,
                "22": 215,
                "23": 139,
                "24": 88,
                "25": 196,
                "26": 0,
                "27": 0,
                "28": 0,
                "29": 0,
                "30": 0,
                "31": 0,
                "32": 0,
                "33": 0,
                "34": 0,
                "35": 0,
                "36": 0,
                "37": 0,
                "38": 0,
                "39": 0,
                "40": 0,
                "41": 0,
                "42": 0,
                "43": 0,
                "44": 0,
                "45": 0,
                "46": 0,
                "47": 0,
                "48": 0,
                "49": 0,
                "50": 0,
                "51": 0,
                "52": 180,
                "53": 120,
                "54": 1,
                "55": 187,
                "56": 125,
                "57": 252,
                "58": 180,
                "59": 113
        }
}
```

Here was my swap function:

```rust
use std::time::{UNIX_EPOCH, SystemTime};

use ethers_contract::abigen;
use ethers::{
    prelude::{SignerMiddleware, Middleware},
    providers::{Provider, Http},
    types::{Address, TransactionRequest, NameOrAddress, U256, Eip1559TransactionRequest},
    signers::LocalWallet
};

use crate::read_from_root;

pub struct TxGas {
    pub max_priority_fee_per_gas: Option<U256>,
    pub max_fee_per_gas: Option<U256>
}

abigen!(UniswapV2Router02, r"[
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint256 amountOut, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline)
]");

pub async fn swap_exact_eth_for_tokens(amount_in: u128, signer: SignerMiddleware<Provider<Http>, LocalWallet>, gas_option: TxGas) {

    let signer_middleware = std::sync::Arc::new(signer);
    let sender_address = signer_middleware.address();

    let uni_v2_router_addr: Address = read_from_root("./contracts/script/state/addresses/uni-v2-router.txt").parse().unwrap();
    let tkn_addr: Address = read_from_root("./contracts/script/state/addresses/token.txt").parse().unwrap();
    let weth_addr: Address = read_from_root("./contracts/script/state/addresses/weth.txt").parse().unwrap();

    let uni_v2_router = UniswapV2Router02::new(uni_v2_router_addr, signer_middleware.clone());

    let mut path = Vec::new();
    path.push(weth_addr);
    path.push(tkn_addr);

    let amount_wei = U256::from(amount_in).checked_mul(U256::from(10_u64.pow(18))).unwrap();

    let tx_data = uni_v2_router.swap_exact_eth_for_tokens(
        (0).into(),
        path,
        sender_address,
        (SystemTime::now().duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs() * 2).into()
    );
    let tx = Eip1559TransactionRequest {
        from: None,
        to: Some(NameOrAddress::Address(uni_v2_router_addr)),
        value: Some(amount_wei),
        data: Some(tx_data.tx.data().unwrap().clone()),
        max_priority_fee_per_gas: gas_option.max_priority_fee_per_gas,
        max_fee_per_gas: gas_option.max_fee_per_gas,
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let response = signer_middleware.send_transaction(tx, None).await.expect("Failed to send transaction");
    println!("My Swap: {:?}", response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is not very explicit, and the fact that the exact same code was working in one situation but not the other was weird.

The code finally ran when I manually provided a gas amount (gas limit) for the `Eip1559TransactionRequest`.

```rs
    let tx = Eip1559TransactionRequest {
        from: None,
        to: Some(NameOrAddress::Address(uni_v2_router_addr)),
        value: Some(amount_wei),
        data: Some(tx_data.tx.data().unwrap().clone()),
        gas: Some(U256::from(500_000)), // LINE ADDED
        max_priority_fee_per_gas: gas_option.max_priority_fee_per_gas,
        max_fee_per_gas: gas_option.max_fee_per_gas,
        ..Default::default()
    };
```